# Need to intergate IDX MLS into a website

Tags: php, mysql

Are there any free IDX (Internet Data Exchange) or MLS (Multiple Listing Service) integration scripts available? These services allow a website to display real estate listings based on user search criteria.

I want to do a website in which I can integrate the MLS data into the site database but I have no idea how to go about it without seeing some type of working script. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @delboud I also plan to design a new website & load IDX data . Any useful  tips or resources about getting IDX data?

Answer (score 5):

IDX (Internet Data Exchange) and MLS (Multiple Listing Service) are terms used in real estate for the online property listing services.  All of the big websites like Homes.com, Realtor.com, and Trulia.com, have access to all or many of the MLS boards around the country and even outside of the US for their property search features.  Most agents also have MLS search though their own sites.  Usually the webhost offers access to their own custom solution or through a third-party like iHomefinder.com or idxbroker.com.

IDX data feeds are usually restricted to realtors and brokers for the MLS boards they are members of.  The realtors or brokers can get a consultant access to the feed.  For the feed we have access to, we had to have authorization forms signed by both realtor and their broker, then fax in before getting access to the ftp for raw feed.  Even the webhosts above have to approval from the MLS board before they will allow access to their search.  The MLS boards have strict rules you must abide by. And of course not all MLS boards are a like so read the rules.

As for software, I have seen some open source software on SourceForge but have not looked any further than that.  Quick search brought up these two.

http://www.real-estate-website.org

http://reos.elazos.com

If anyone else has any others please add them.

Comment: The reos.elazos.com link is broken. The main site there is from Spain in Spanish. Probably not going to help with the MLS in the US.

Comment: Your first link is now an ad site for a browser add-on, and the second one is a broken link.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the MLS are now changing their data feed to adhere to RETS standards.But data returned from each MLS is usually different from others.So most likely you will need to develop a custom plugin to pull data ,parse it to store in DB and display it to your customers

Answer (score 2):

There is a WordPress plugin that does a very good job of this called dsIDXexpress provided by Diverse Solutions.