# Intergating IDX MLS into a website

Tags: php, mysql

I read this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300482/need-to-intergate-idx-mls-into-a-website), I am creating a real estate site. I am familiar with PHP and MySQL And ready to work on script as well but really can not find any start. I want to form a PHP scripts that will update the data nightly, via an FTP Zip file from his MLS company and import it into the MySQL database.

-RETS accounts and stuff are ready to be implement

Comment: Your question is much too vague. Break it down into one simple question instead of multiple questions rolled into one. If you have multiple questions then ask multiple questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is illegal. The company that has access the MLS database is not allowed to share this data with others. That's against the contracts they had to sign in order to obtain access.

Instead, you should apply to become a "technical provider" yourself, by contacting your local real estate board (for example, the California Bureau of Real Estate: http://dre.ca.gov/). This will give you your own private access to the latest MLS data, which you can then save to your own database via PHP/MySql.

Once you have an account with a real estate board, a helpful library for saving the MLS data to your database is phRETS (https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki).